# Emit http requests + debounce on Kendo field changes

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, kendo-ui-angular2

I have a method which is called everytime some input text is change. (Basically it is a search).
I want to delay post/get request so if user quickly types, only one request will be send to server.

I was thinking something like that:

```
public partnerFilterChange(value)
{
    if (this.partnersSubscriptions)
        this.partnersSubscriptions.unsubscribe();

    this.partnersSubscriptions = this.partnersService.list({ filter: value })
        .debounceTime(5000)
        .subscribe(partners =>
        {
            delete this.partnersSubscriptions;
            this.partners = partners;
        });
}
```

but it is not working.

Http request is executed immediately, not after 5 seconds. I also try `delay` instead `debounceTime`.

**Edited:**

I am using [kendo drop down list component and its change event](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/#toc-filtering), so I have no control over the function call, only on subscribing to http request.

Comment: Use `switchMap` for search filters. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#listen-for-search-terms

Comment: You need to restructure your code so that the `debounceTime()` operator is located BETWEEN the observable emitting the filter values and the observable making the HTTP requests. Something like `this.filter.valueChanges.debounceTime(400).mergeMap(filter => this. partnersService.search(term))` . See https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html

Comment: You can always push the changes received from Kendo to your own, custom observable. If you want to *debounce* the emitted values, they **must be wrapped inside an observable**.

Comment: @AngularFrance: thanks - Just one tiny little problem. I can not use form.valueChanges since value is not changed. Event (key down) on DropDown is handled internally and form value is changed when you select item, not when searching.

Comment: `form.valueChanges` only works for raw Angular fields. Like I said, since you're using Kendo, you need to push the values received from Kendo into your own observable. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment. You can't use `form.get('fieldName').valueChanges` directly since you're using Kendo. But you CAN push the values received from Kendo to your own, custom observable, thus replicating the behavior of `valueChanges`:

```ts
class AppComponent {
  // This is your own, custom observable that you'll subscribe to.
  // It will contain a stream of filter values received from Kendo.
  private _filterValues: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

  constructor() {
    // Start from your custom stream, debounce values, and run http query
    this._filterValues.asObservable()
      .debounceTime(400)
      .mergeMap(value => this.partnersService.list({ filter: value }))
      .subscribe(partners => this.partners = partners);
  }

  // This method is called by Kendo every time the field value changes.
  handleFilter(value) {
    // Push the value in the custom stream.
    this._filterValues.next(value);
  }
}
```

NB. This code assumes that `this.partnersService.list()` returns an observable.

With this code, every time you update the field, the list of partners should be refreshed and the debounce should be applied. (I haven't tested the code, you might need to adapt it to your own use case.)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in my Angular 2 app, I am just going to paste my solution:

```
subscribeToSearchQueryChanges(){
        const sub = Observable.fromEvent(this.panelSuggestionBox.nativeElement, 'keyup')
            .debounceTime(300)
            .filter((kbE: KeyboardEvent) => {
                return !(kbE['code'] === 'Space' || kbE.key === 'ArrowDown' || kbE.key === 'ArrowUp' || kbE.key === 'Enter' || kbE.key === 'Tab' || kbE.key === 'Shift')
            })
            .map(() => _.trim(this.panelSuggestionBox.nativeElement.value) )
            .filter((term: string) => term.length > 2 )
            .switchMap((term: string) => this.suggestionService.getSuggestions(this.suggestionTypes, term))
            .subscribe((suggestions: Suggestion[]) => {
                this.suggestionsData = this.suggestionService.groupSuggestions(suggestions);
                this.toggleSuggestionList();
            }, err => {
                console.error('suggestions failed', err);
                this.removeSubscription(sub);
                this.subscribeToSearchQueryChanges();
            });

        this.addSubscription(sub);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, Output, HostListener, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-user-search',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  template: `
    <form role="search" class="navbar-form-custom form-inline" [formGroup]="searchForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="user-search">Search</label>
        <input
          id="user-search"
          class="form-control"
          name="input"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search Co-worker"
          formControlName="search"
        />
      </div>
    </form>
  `
})
export class UserSearchComponent {

  searchForm = new FormGroup({
    search: new FormControl('')
  });

  @Output() search: Observable<string> = this.searchForm.valueChanges
    .map(form => form.search)
    .debounceTime(700)
    .distinctUntilChanged();

  @HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])
  cancelSearch(event) {
    if (event.code === 'Escape') {
      this.searchForm.reset();
      // this.searchControl.setValue('', {emitEvent: true});
    }
  }

}
```

### Usage

Where the $event value is the search term and (search) will be called first when 700ms has passed and the input is not the same

```
<my-user-search (search)="handleSearch($event)"></my-user-search>
```

Comment: Just one tiny little problem. I can not use form.valueChanges since value is not changed. Event (key down) on DropDown is handled internally and form value is changed when you select item, not when searching.